# What determines whether a browser will open or download a .txt file?

Tags: file, browser, download, rendering, ascii

Let me start by saying that I am aware that you can specify the Content-Disposition in the header and use either "attachment" or "inline" and this question is **NOT** about that (at least not directly).

I have a file with a .txt extension.  I am noticing different browser behavior dependent on the content of that .txt file.  If my file contains alphanumeric characters and I paste the location of the file into the URL bar of (say) Chrome, the file opens in the browser.

If my file contains an ["SI"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%5EO) character the file is downloaded instead of opened in the browser.

At first I thought it might be because "SI" is a control code, but "CR" and "LF" are also control codes and the file displays in the browser when they are present.  The file even opens in the Chrome when there is a "DC2" character present in the .txt file.

My question is: At the file content level, what determines whether or not a file is displayed or downloaded?

(I realize this may vary by browser, but if there is something that's at least somewhat reliable, it would be helpful to know)

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** (based on answer from Sam):

When the "SI" or "DC2" character is in the first 1000 or so characters of the text file it will be downloaded, if those characters are after the first 1000 or so characters the file is displayed in the browser.

Comment: In my case STX symbol forced Edge (99.0.1150.46 64-bit) to download a .txt file. Without this symbol Edge shows the file contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior of the browser when you send it a file is going to be based on the content-type header sent by your server.  If you aren't explicitly setting it yourself, your web server may attempt to make a best guess based on the first few bytes of the file.

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime_magic.html

Comment: This led me to play around with the file that I was working with and discovered that the placement of the "special" characters within the file did in fact matter.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The order how is determined if Save dialog is shown by a browser.

- [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) set by web developer in Apache or cgi. By specs this is what we should do.
- Content-Type header's [MIME type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#applicationoctet-stream) set by web developer in Apache or cgi

> application/octet-stream ... browsers ... treat it as if the Content-Disposition header was set
> to attachment, and propose a "Save As" dialog.

- Content-Type header's MIME type determined and set by a web server. e.g. Apache has two methods:

  - Apache's [assign MIME type](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype) by mapping patterns in the URI or filenames. e.g. `AddType application/octet-stream .pkg`
  - Apache's [mod_mime_magic](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime_magic.html#mimemagicfile), **if it's installed and enabled** by web developer

  > ... This module is active only if the magic file is specified by the
  > MimeMagicFile directive.
- [HTML5 download attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) set by web developer in html file, or in JS (I did not test if it does not override the above)

If none of the above applied, the browser is going above specs and deciding by itself.

In the following screenshot, response headers don't mention Content-Disposition, nor Content-Type. On the left side we can see a part of the file was transferred (I did not click on Open or Save) and we can see browser stating it's "application/octed-stream"

My assumption from this is that browser after receiving a part of the file decided it would not be sane to show it inline (on the screen), declared the MIME and offered the Save dialog.

[image: browser screenshot]

The screenshot was made from Developer Tools of Firefox after I pasted URL of the file in Omnibox, opened DevTools and pressed Enter in Omnibox to "go" to pasted address.