# html file is getting downloaded instead of getting redirected to it

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I am trying to redirect my request to a page "/access_blocked.html" from inside a java.servlet.Filter. But when I am trying to do it using `response.redirect("/access_blocked.html")`, my file "access_blocked.html" is getting downloaded on my browser instead of getting redirected.
FYI - The request is coming from the browsers anchor tag and the server is designed using spring boot which has tomcat embedded.

I have also tried to forward the request with `request.getRequestDispatcher("/access_blocked.html").forward(request,response)` but got no success.

```
@Component
public class TransactionFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        String url = req.getRequestURI();
        if (url.startsWith("/sdks/")) {
            res.sendRedirect("/access_blocked.html");
            return;
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

Expected result - On my browser the request should get redirected to "/access_blocked.html".

Comment: Sounds strange.. Are you setting any response headers anywhere (e.g. in another Filter?). Or maybe the access_blocked.html contains any special characters? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19257824/what-determines-whether-a-browser-will-open-or-download-a-txt-file

Comment: Yes I have tried setting the header to "text/html" but still getting same issue. When I try to access "access_blocked.html" from browser address bar, it is accessible.

Comment: Tried changing the file name but no success. File only contains simple characters like this - <html>
<body>
 <div>Access blocked to this page</div>
 
</body>
</html>

Answer (score -1):

Did you get the solution to this, I'm facing same kind of problem.

I found one solution to this problem, that instead of writing "txt/html" simply write ".html" . Its the only thing working for me.